# how to quickly create a test database for Cucumber-jvm?

Tags: java, hibernate, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber-jvm to test the behaviour of the legacy system I'm working on at work. I have to use Java 1.5 and Hibernate 3.3, upgrading is not an option. Since, during my tests, it stores some objects in the database, I have created a new development database.

What bothers me is that I have to manually drop the records (using a sql script) everytime I'll rerun my tests, or they'll fail. And anyone else wanting to run them would have to do the same. I want to quickly and automatically clean my test database, by either:

- Creating an empty database and populating it with what I need, or
- Using an already existing database, droping the records before starting the tests.

What I have so far: I'm using the cucumber-junit plugin, and the RunTests class redirects to my test database:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
    features = "test/resources/cucumber",
    format = "html:target/cucumber"
)
public class RunTests {
    private static Configuration configuration;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void preparaBase() {
        // gets the mapped configuration to the db
        configuration = HibernateUtil.getConfiguration();

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "test-db-url");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "user");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "pass");
//      configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        // rebuilds the configuration using my test database
        HibernateUtil.rebuildSessionFactory(configuration);
    }
}
```

I have tried using the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property with the `create-drop` value and using the `import.sql` file to prepare the database, but it takes ages to start the tests and it seems that it's not detecting my import.sql file.

Sadly, using Maven and its excellent maven-sql-plugin is not an option (I have suggested a switch to Maven, to no avail). Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

I used this [ScriptRunner](http://pastebin.com/f10584951) class as such:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
    features = "test/resources/cucumber",
    format = "html:target/cucumber"
)
public class RunTests {
    private static Configuration configuration;
    String url = "test-db-url";
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "pass";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void preparaBase() {
        // gets the mapped configuration to the db
        configuration = HibernateUtil.getConfiguration();

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", pass);

        // rebuilds the configuration using my test database
        HibernateUtil.rebuildSessionFactory(configuration);

        // executes a script stored in test/resources/cucumber
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn, false, true);

            runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test/resources/cucumber/db.sql")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```